# Add cards in html via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've added 3 cards through a loop. My problem here is that I want to put these 3 cards together, not below each other. I want them to be ordered horizontally.

```js
arr = [{
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Job": "Programmer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Job": "Programmer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kevin",
    "Job": "Scientist"
  },
];

$.each(arr, function(i) {
  var templateString = '<div class="card mb-2 box-shadow">    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">      <div class="card-body">  <h5>' + arr[i].Name + '</h5> </p></div> </div>';
  $('#test').append(templateString);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add row class in your div with Id test `<div id="test" class="row"></div>` if you want them to be horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
#test
{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: thank you . I just want to have 3 cards in each row what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

use this css for your div `test`

```
#test
{
 position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
 }
```

a working demo:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/hdwbf5n2/6/

Answer (score 1):

By default, Div adds children vertically due to default block property of Div, if you want to add items in div in horizontal direction then change the display property to flex with flex-direction should be set to row(it is by default row so you can ignore it).
because you are using bootstrap here so you can also use the `row` class here

```
 <div id="test" class="row"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="test" style="display:flex"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style in div like this:-

```
<div id="test" style = "display: block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code as below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="test" class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var arr = [
            { "Name": "Peter", "Job": "Programmer" },
            { "Name": "John", "Job": "Programmer" },
            { "Name": "Kevin", "Job": "Scientist" },
        ];

        $.each(arr, function (i) {
            var templateString = '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="card mb-2 box-shadow"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body"><h5>' + arr[i].Name + '</h5></p></div></div></div>';
            $('#test').append(templateString);
        })
    </script>
```

Maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with below code.
    <script>
       arr = [
         {"Name":"Peter","Job":"Programmer"},
         {"Name":"John","Job":"Programmer"},
         {"Name":"Kevin","Job":"Scientist"},
       ];

       $.each(arr, function(i){
         var templateString = '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="card mb-2 box-shadow">    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">      <div class="card-body">  <h5>'+arr[i].Name+'</h5> </p></div> </div></div>';
         $('#test').append(templateString);
       })
    </script>    

    <div class="row">
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply solution is using proper usage of bootstrap grid. You could have used `row` class for your `<div id="test">` and append `<div class="col-4">` for having three cards in row. Below is the working snippet for the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="test"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    arr = [{
        "Name": "Peter",
        "Job": "Programmer"
      },
      {
        "Name": "John",
        "Job": "Programmer"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Kevin",
        "Job": "Scientist"
      },
    ];

    $.each(arr, function(i) {
      var templateString =
        '<div class="col-sm-4 card mb-2 box-shadow">    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">      <div class="card-body p-0">  <h5>' +
        arr[i].Name + '</h5> </p></div> </div>';
      $('#test').append(templateString);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I remove the photo and title padding?

Comment: You can apply `p-0` class to `card-body`. Updated in Snippet. Have a look

Comment: not wotking , plase fix show mobile in row 1 column

Comment: check now. make it `col-sm-4` if you want single column in mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just adding the class `row` to your test div: `<div id="test" class="row"></div>`

Here is the full snippet:

```js
arr = [{
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Job": "Programmer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Job": "Programmer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kevin",
    "Job": "Scientist"
  },
];

$.each(arr, function(i) {
  let templateString = '<div class="card mb-2 box-shadow">    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">      <div class="card-body">  <h5>' + arr[i].Name + '</h5> </p></div> </div>';
  $('#test').append(templateString);
})
```

```css
/* not relevant only for visibility within snippet*/
.card {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div id="test" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="test"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    arr = [{
        "Name": "Peter",
        "Job": "Programmer"
      },
      {
        "Name": "John",
        "Job": "Programmer"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Kevin",
        "Job": "Scientist"
      },
    ];

    $.each(arr, function(i) {
      var templateString =
        '<div class="col-sm-4 card mb-2 box-shadow">    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://safarset.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IMG-20190423-WA0029.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">      <div class="card-body p-0">  <h5>' +
        arr[i].Name + '</h5> </p></div> </div>';
      $('#test').append(templateString);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add some explanation. What the difference between your answer and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56767084